# C# Adding Items to a List that contain both another Class along with a List<Class>

Tags: c#, list, class

I have been searching the internet for multiple days trying to find the answer that I am looking for with no luck.  I have tried multiple variations of the code with all the same result.

I have built a couple of small classes, ClassNames & StudentNames.  Then I am trying to incorporate both into another class called List of Class.  Everything works good, until I turn the last item into a List.  I can make it work with breaking things out, but I would rather learn how I can do it in a "single" command.  I figure there must be a way to do this, but it just is eluding me as to what I should be doing.  Everything works until: private static readonly List MeadowlarkClasses = new()

```
namespace Testing
{
    internal class Testing
    {
        public class clsStudentName
        {
            public int? StudentID { get; set; }
            public string? StudentFirstName { get; set; }
            public string? StudentMiddleInitial { get; set; }
            public string? StudentLastName { get; set; }


            public clsStudentName()
            {

            }

            public clsStudentName(
                int? intStudentID,
                string? strStudentFirstName,
                string? strStudentMiddleInitial,
                string? strStudentLastName)
            {
                StudentID = intStudentID;
                StudentFirstName = strStudentFirstName;
                StudentMiddleInitial = strStudentMiddleInitial;
                StudentLastName = strStudentLastName;

            }

        }

        public class clsClassName
        {
            public int? ClassID { get; set; }
            public string? ClassName { get; set; }

            public clsClassName()
            {

            }

            public clsClassName(
                int intClassID,
                string strClassName
                )
            {
                ClassID = intClassID;
                ClassName = strClassName;

            }

        }

        public class clsClasses
        {
            public clsClassName? clsClassNm { get; set; } = new clsClassName();
            public List<clsStudentName>? clsStudentNames { get; set; } = new List<clsStudentName>();

            clsClasses()
            {

            }

            public clsClasses(
                clsClassName? ClassNm,
                List<clsStudentName>? lstStudentNames
                )
            {
                clsClassNm = ClassNm;
                clsStudentNames = lstStudentNames;
            }
        }

        public static readonly clsClassName MathClass = new(
            1,
            "Math"
            );

        public static readonly clsClassName ArtClass = new(
            2,
            "Art"
            );

        public static readonly clsStudentName AndyApple = new(
            1,
            "Andy",
            "",
            "Apple"
            );

        public static readonly clsStudentName BettyBoo = new(
            2,
            "Betty",
            "",
            "Boo"
            );

        public static readonly clsStudentName CarlCrown = new(
            3,
            "Carl",
            "",
            "Crown"
            );

        public static readonly clsClasses MathClasses = new(
            MathClass,
            new List<clsStudentName>()
            {
                AndyApple,
                BettyBoo
            }
            );

        public static readonly clsClasses ArtClasses = new(
            ArtClass,
            new List<clsStudentName>()
            {
                BettyBoo,
                CarlCrown
            }
            );

        private static readonly List<clsClasses> MeadowlarkClasses = new()
            {
                new() 
                {
                    new clsClassName(1, "Math"),
                    new List<clsStudentName>()
                        {
                            new()
                            {
                                StudentID = 1,
                                StudentFirstName = "Mother",
                                StudentLastName = "Teresa"
                            },
                            new()
                            {
                                StudentID = 2,
                                StudentFirstName = "Father",
                                StudentLastName = "Dowling"
                            }

                        }

                }

            };

    }

}
```

I have broken things apart to try to get more information, try to take it in smaller steps to try to figure out what I am doing wrong, but I just can't seem to find the answer.  I would appreciate any help that anyone can give!

Comment: Side note: `clsClassName` is.....quite a name. You may want to review [Microsoft's naming convention recommendations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/identifier-names).

Comment: You seem to have posted more code than what would be reasonable for your issue. Please read [ask] and how to make a [mre]; providing a MRE helps users answer your question and future users relate to your issue.

Comment: @gunr2171 -- My appologies for not posting just right, I wanted to show what I had tried to do to complete my thought process and I am terribly sorry for not following MS Naming Conventions . . .

Answer (score 4):

Your code, as posted in the question, is more or less fine. You really just needed to get the syntax right in your `MeadowlarkClasses` declaration. It was not a fundamental issue with how you defined your classes or C#. You just got the syntax wrong.

Also, as it has been pointed out, your naming convention is horrible. No doubt that made it harder to reason with your code. And, you had mixed constructors that weren't needed.

My suggestion to you is to refactor your classes and implement them like this:

```
public class Student(int? id, string? firstName, string? middleInitial, string? lastName)
{
    public int? Id => id;
    public string? FirstName => firstName;
    public string? MiddleInitial => middleInitial;
    public string? LastName => lastName;
}

public class Subject(int id, string name)
{
    public int? Id => id;
    public string? Name => name;
}

public class Enrolments(Subject? subject, List<Student>? students)
{
    public Subject? Subject => subject;
    public List<Student>? Students => students;
}
```

Now the rest of your code is straightforward:

```
public static readonly Subject Math = new(1, "Math");
public static readonly Subject Art = new(2, "Art");
public static readonly Student AndyApple = new(1, "Andy", "", "Apple");
public static readonly Student BettyBoo = new(2, "Betty", "", "Boo");
public static readonly Student CarlCrown = new(3, "Carl", "", "Crown");

public static readonly Enrolments MathEnrolments = new(Math, new List<Student>() { AndyApple, BettyBoo } );
public static readonly Enrolments ArtEnrolments = new(Art, new List<Student>() { BettyBoo, CarlCrown } );
private static readonly List<Enrolments> MeadowlarkEnrolments = new()
{
    new Enrolments(
        Math,
        new List<Student>()
        {
            new Student(1, "Mother", "", "Teresa"),
            new Student(2, "Father", "", "Dowling"),
        })
};
```

Comment: `Enrolments` is a great name!

Comment: @stuartd - I took the view that an enrolment is a student joining the class, but from the class' point-of-view there are multiple enrolments. The alternative is to have a `Enrolment` class with a single `Subject` and a single `Student` and then have `var enrolments = new List<Enrolment>();`.

Comment: Singular or plural is a tricky choice looking at the definition of the word, but it seems to me that plural is a better choice here

Answer (score 1):

A couple of problems with the code:

1. The empty constructor for `clsClasses` needs to be `public` to use it in the initialization
2. You've mixed up the constructor and initialization syntax a bit.

This compiles - I wasn't clear whether you meant to use the constructors or initialization so I went with the latter.

```
/*

Assumes the constructor is public:

public clsClasses()
{
}

*/
private static readonly List <clsClasses> MeadowlarkClasses = new() {
    new clsClasses {
        clsClassNm = new clsClassName(1, "Math"),
        clsStudentNames = new List <clsStudentName> () {
            new() {
                StudentID = 1,
                StudentFirstName = "Mother",
                StudentLastName = "Teresa"
            },
            new() {
                StudentID = 2,
                StudentFirstName = "Father",
                StudentLastName = "Dowling"
            }
        }
    }
};
```

To reiterate what was said in the comments - naming things is hard and naming conventions can be ignored, but.. here are my opinions.

One thing I would highly recommend is dropping the [Hungarian notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) (the `cls`) as it's very easy to see in the IDE that this does represent a class, and extra 'noise' in the name - even noise which seems like it could be helpful - makes it harder to tell what something represents at a glance.

And even though I realise the class does represent a 'class' - in the sense of a 'lesson' - in C# the concept of `class` is pretty much hardcoded into our brains.. so another name would be good there. I would choose one which is singular as the class represents one subject and a list of students. `Course`, perhaps? I guess it depends what kind of education this represents.

And - for the sake of completeness - the `clsStudentName` class contains the student name *and* the ID, so something like `Student` would be a better name.

I hope you don't mind this unasked-for advice - many times in the past I've made mistakes caused by bad class names, so now I do try to make them as clear as possible.

Comment: . . Thank you for your help.  I know I am not a master programmer, but a farmer by trade.  I do this type of thing just to keep my mind busy from missing my kids.  I try to come up with something that I would like to solve and work on it.  I have it working, not as neat as yours, but now that I understand the principles, I can dig deeper and see if I can make it better.  Thanks again!